Disagreement over classification as duplicate
Yesterday I opened a question, When authors write "model of the data" is this a shorthand for "model of the data generating process", that was marked duplicate of Why do we use term “population” instead of “Data-generating process”?. I would like your opinion on why they might be considered duplicates?
Maybe I should change the title to

When authors write "model of the data" is this a shorthand for "model of what generated the data",

so that people don't get trapped in the "Data-generating process vs Population" issue?

Just try editing and see if there are votes to re-open. My own opinion is that this is too minor (and too awkward) an edit to be persuasive, but that is just one view.

I'm with @NickCox here. How is "model of the data" an abuse of terminology compared to "model of the system that we measured"? I honestly don't see the difference in the first place. And Nick's comment that this is necessarily a question of philosophy is spot on. It's a question of whether you focus on what you observe (the data) or any underlying reality that generated the data. Of course we are always interested in the latter, but the former is the only thing we can model.

Sharing the thoughts articulated in the first two comments, I had voted to keep the post closed.  Might I suggest that posing questions concerning patterns of terminology that might be subjective (and therefore are not on topic) is best done in our chat room?  I believe you would have obtained many answers in much shorter time.

@StephanKolassa, well that is your answer to my original question, and a valid answer. What I don't see is why it does justify considering the two questions the same question...

@whuber, I was just following the suggested steps as stated in https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions. But thanks for the suggestion.

I was not involved in the voting to close the original on CV as a duplicate. But often there can be several grounds to close a question. The over-arching issue to me is whether that question on CV is (potentially) a good, clear, distinct question to which I would reply Not yet. I don't think writing model of the data is especially good writing, but I wouldn't presume to know that people saying that really mean something different about a generating process. In short, it's a loaded question.

Ok, so maybe my problem is that I assumed that it meant "data generation process" but it might mean other things. Maybe I should delete all the references to DGP and simply ask if "modeling the data" is good technical english or sloppy technical english?

Again, try it to see how convincing that is.
